# TypeORM CLI generate migration - Error Unable to compile TypeScript

Tags: typescript, nestjs, typeorm, nestjs-typeorm

I am trying to generate a migration, using TypeORM CLI. Here are the scripts in package.json:

````
"typeorm": "typeorm-ts-node-esm -d ./src/typeorm.config.ts",
"typeorm:migrate": "npm run typeorm -- migration:run",
"typeorm:revert": "npm run typeorm -- migration:revert",
"typeorm:generate": "npm run typeorm -- migration:generate ./src/data/migrations/$npm_config_name"```
````

The command, that I am running in a terminal:

```
npm run typeorm:migrate --name=migration_name
```

Error, that I receive:

```
Property 'user' does not exist on type 'Request<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs, Record<string, any>>'
```

The error is from the part of code, that tries to access `user` property of `Request`.

The user property was added in `index.d.ts` file in the following way:

```
import {
  Request as ExpressRequest,
  UserAuthResponseDto,
} from 'src/common/types/types';

declare module 'express' {
  export interface Request extends ExpressRequest {
    user?: UserAuthResponseDto;
  }
}
```

The code does not throw any errors, when running it in development mode or when building it, the error only appears when trying to generate a new migration.

Used packages and their versions:

```
{
    ...
    "@types/express": "4.17.17",
    "ts-node": "10.9.1",
    "typescript": "4.9.5",
    "@nestjs/common": "9.4.0",
    "@nestjs/core": "9.4.0",
    "@nestjs/platform-express": "9.4.0",
    "@nestjs/typeorm": "9.0.1",
    "pg": "8.10.0",
    "typeorm": "0.3.15"
    ...
  },
```

The code in `typeorm.config.ts` file:

```
import { DataSource } from 'typeorm';

import { ENV } from './common/enums/enums';
import { UserEntity, WorkerEntity } from './entities/entities';

const { TYPE, HOST, PORT, USER, PASSWORD, NAME } = ENV.DB;

export default new DataSource({
  type: TYPE,
  host: HOST,
  port: PORT,
  username: USER,
  password: PASSWORD,
  database: NAME,
  logging: true,
  entities: [UserEntity, WorkerEntity],
  migrations: ['dist/data/migrations/*.js'],
});
```

It seems like typeorm doesn't see `index.d.ts` file.
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Found a workaround, but I don't think this is the best solution:
I commented the code, which uses req.user, generated migrations, uncommented code. It worked